How to train tensorflow Variables next to gpflow Parameters
I want to implement warped GPs using GPFlow, following this interesting paper.
In my setup I define very simple example data
X = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.linspace(0,2*pi,10)[:,np.newaxis],dtype="float64")
Y = tf.sin(X)
warper = WarpingFunction()
Z = warper.warp(Y)

GP model
import gpflow as gp
kern = gp.kernels.SquaredExponential()
model = gp.models.GPR((X,Z),kernel = kern)

and a warping class
class WarpingFunction(tf.Module):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(WarpingFunction, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.a = tf.Variable(initial_value=1.0)
        self.b = tf.Variable(initial_value=3.0)

    def warp(self,x):
        z = self.a*tf.math.pow(x,self.b)
        return z

    def inverse(self, z):
        x = tf.math.sign(z) * tf.math.pow(tf.abs(z), 1.0 / self.b) / self.a
        return x

    def grad_warp(self,y):
        dy = self.a * self.b * y**(self.b-1)
        return dy

    def loss(self, y):
        log_vec = tf.math.log(self.grad_warp(y))
        loss_sum = tf.reduce_sum(log_vec)
        return loss_sum

to do my warping (in this case cubing).
My question arises when I am thinking about how to train the Variables a,b I defined in WarpingFunction using the gpflow optimizers. My current thought would have been to supply the optimizer with the additional parameters a,b and writing a custom loss function
def loss() -> tf.Tensor:
    Z_predicted,_ = model.predict_y(X)
    squared_error = (Z_predicted - Z) ** 2
    return tf.reduce_mean(squared_error)  +warper.loss(Z_predicted)

opti = gp.optimizers.Scipy()
opti.minimize(loss,model.trainable_variables + warper.trainable_variables())


I have not found anything in the doc or on SO. I saw in the documentation that gpflow has a Parameter class, however the trainable_variables parameter of opti.minimize only allows tf.Variable types.
I am not well versed enough in tensorflow to write my own training loop, especially not in combination with the GP problem.
Any and all hints and tips are welcome!
